# Compass - Changing default of "compass watch"

Tags: sass, compass-sass

With SASS you are required to create a config.rb which manages the location of the app. I've recently changed the name of this file to "sass_config.rb" and can't figure out how to change the default of "compass watch" so that it finds my renamed file.

To clarify, when I run the following command compass correctly finds the file and continues with its normal behavior:

```
compass -c watch sass_config.rb
```

But when I run:

```
compass watch
```

It says:

```
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, 
you have left off the directory argument.
```

How can I fix this behavior so it sees the file has been renamed by just running "compass watch"?

Comment: Why did you need to rename config.rb?

Comment: I had another config.yml file in the directory and just wanted to make it clear what config.rb was for...

Comment: config.rb and config.yml don't sound like they conflict.  The appropriate fix seems to be "put the name back the way it was".

Comment: so is it NOT possible to change the name then? obviously I could do that but that wasn't what I was asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration filename cannot be arbitrarily modified.  It is hard coded within Compass to be in one of 5 locations (soon to be 4).

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/192107cb4f17bef52fdd8c0d961fe77f3edb44c4/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb#L137

```
# TODO: Deprecate the src/config.rb location.
KNOWN_CONFIG_LOCATIONS = ['config/compass.rb', ".compass/config.rb", "config/compass.config", "config.rb", "src/config.rb"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a compass project by

`compass create`

after that you copy the OLD config.rb content to the created one from copass.

Now try

`compass watch`